# data-binding in Spring MVC vs Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, data-binding

Two-way data binding is one of the popular feature of Angularjs. However, data-binding can be achieved by Spring framework as well. So, what shall be the benefit of using Angularjs data-binding in Spring MVC application? Can someone please explain this with an example.

Comment: Spring MVC is a framework to build web server applications and Angular is a javascript framework to construct single page applications. The two frameworks targets are completely different so it makes no sense to compare them.

Comment: DaniCE, Does it mean, either I should go with Spring MVC or with Angularjs but don't mix them.